Impossible to link against target defined in another jamfile, relative sources mixed across projects?
In LibA/jamfile I have:
import path ;
SOURCES = [ path.glob-tree src : *.cpp ] ;
lib LibA : $(SOURCES) ;

In LibB/jamfile I have:
import path ;
SOURCES = [ path.glob-tree src : *.cpp ] ;
lib LibB : $(SOURCES) ../LibA//LibA/<link>static ;

The problem I have is that I cannot build target LibB, I have the error:
error: Unable to find file or target named
error:     'src/b_object.cpp'
error: referred to from project at
error:     '/D:/dev/myproject/LibA'

which is very strange because b_object.cpp is contained in LibB/src not in  LibA/src so it should be used to build LibA (which seems to be the case: "referred to from project at").
Any idea ?

Outdated answer, see my other answer. I do not delete this one to provide resources on b2 and help search engines.
There exists two different glob-tree commands in b2 !

glob-tree, the built-in one which is always available
path.glob-tree from path module which requires you import path ; first

The first one will search relatively to the jamfile which calls the command.
The second one will, apparently, search relatively to the current working directory (this can be tested by calling b2 ./LibA//LibA from LibA parent directory).
Only path.glob-tree seems to allow specifying root(s) directory to search in. If you really need this feature I guess you should specify the path to the jamfile directory in the root(s), using the built-in rule path-constant, like this:
path-constant LibA_ROOT : . ;
import path ;
SOURCES = [ path.glob-tree "$(LibA_ROOT)/src" : *.cpp ] ; # will be rooted paths
lib LibA : $(SOURCES) ;

I advise you always use path.glob-tree like this in order to avoid perplexing errors the day you copy-paste the line to another jamfile, or when you starting linking against your target from another jamfile.
An alternative to path-constant LibA_ROOT : . ; could be LibA_ROOT = "$(MyProject_TOP)/LibA" ; with MyProject_TOP defined and exported in the jamroot ( path-constant MyProject_TOP : . ; modules.poke : MyProject_TOP : $(MyProject_TOP) ; )
One more thing: using SOURCES = [ path.glob-tree "$(LibA_ROOT)/src" : ... ] will apparently cause the paths in SOURCES to be rooted which can impact how b2 processes them. For instance I saw that after this change all the obj would be generated in the same directory (instead of being generated in a subdirectory matching the one containing the .cpp source). This means that if you have C++ source files with the same name in different directories below src/ they will cause a clash when building ... If this is a problem for you I guess you could use instead:
# Return the list of relative paths from a root and a list of paths below root (they must have root as a parent directory)
# Example: my-relative-path(/a/b, [/a/b/c/d1, /a/b/c/d2]) -> [c/d1, c/d2]
# Inspired by b2's path.relative rule, with the following differences:
# - root_path can be rooted or not
# - paths can be rooted or not
# - work on files as well as directories
# - work on a list of paths, returning the list of relative paths
# note: I am not sure if all paths should be quoted to be robust to whitespaces...
rule my-relative-path ( root_path : paths * )
{
    local root_path_rooted = [ path.root $(root_path) "/" ] ; # yes, this also work on MS Windows
    local result ;
    for local path in $(paths)
    {
        local path_rooted = [ path.root $(path) "/" ] ;
        local path_basename = [ path.basename $(path_rooted) ] ;
        local path_parent = [ path.parent $(path_rooted) ] ;
        local rel_parent_path = [ path.relative $(path_parent) $(root_path_rooted) ] ;
        local path_joined = [ path.join $(rel_parent_path) $(path_basename) ] ;
 
        result += $(path_joined) ;
    }
    return $(result) ;
}

SOURCES = [ my-relative-path $(LibA_ROOT) : [ path.glob-tree "$(LibA_ROOT)/src" : *.cpp ] ] ;


(answer provided in b2 discussion by grisumbras, credit to him)
To glob in a subdirectory use the project rule:
rule glob-tree-ex ( paths + : wildcards + : excludes * )

For example:
SOURCES = [ glob-tree-ex src : *.cpp ] ;

